# nginx configuration to allow allias url to access my current url

Tags: 14.04, nginx

Mu current Nginx configuration is working fine with this url:
https://myhostname.com

But I have created a different alias for same server, say myhostname1

Now when I try to access the url

https://myhostname1.com

it throws error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://hostname?pingpong=2831234.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://myhostname.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'https://myhostname1.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Both the host myhostname and myhostname1 is pointing to same IP and DNS entry.

I tried adding this line to my nginx configuration but that seems not working

```
   location / {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
..........
```

But still that doesn't seems to be working. Can anyone please help wher I am missing.

Comment: May i ask why you cannot redirect automatically at nginx level all requests to `myhostname1` to `myhostname` ?

Comment: myhostname1 and myhostname both are same server  just different names.. how can i do that?

Comment: And yes.. I just dont want to do redirect.. i want my url to be myhostname1 always while browsing..

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myhostname myhostname1;
    access_log /some/path/access.log;
    error_log /some/path/error.log;
    root /some/path/;

    location / {
        if ($http_origin ~* (https?://myhostname|https?://myhostname1)) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        }
        #
        autoindex on;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php ;
    }
}
```

More docs and examples [here](http://marcel.zurreck.com/enable-cross-origin-requests-cors-nginx/).

A regex like this may work for all `myhostnameXXX` where XXX are digits (edited)

```
if ($http_origin ~* (https?:myhostname([0-9]+)?)) {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
}
```

Also, note that both domains are served by the same block :

```
    server_name myhostname myhostname1;
```